# Prove that $M'=\left\{\:x(t)\in{L_2}_{[0,1)}:\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(t)}{t}dt=0\:\right\}$ is closed. Which procedure?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Show that $M$ is closed in ${L_2}_{[1,\infty)}$
>
> $$M=\left\{\:x(t)\in{L_2}_{[1,\infty)}:\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x(t)}{t}dt=0\:\right\}$$

Answer on Math.SE: Assume that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ in $L^{2}[1,\infty)$ which $x_{n}\in M$, then
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x(t)}{t}dt\right|&=\left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x(t)-x_{n}(t)}{t}dt+\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x_{n}(t)}{t}dt\right|\\
&=\left|\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x(t)-x_{n}(t)}{t}dt\right|\\
&\leq\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{t^{2}}dt\right)^{1/2}\|x_{n}-x\|_{L^{2}[1,\infty)}\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

If now we consider  $M'=\left\{\:x(t)\in{L_2}_{[0,1)}:\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x(t)}{t}dt=0\:\right\}$

I thought of using the same procedure as above. I applied it and everything went alright. However I was told the procedure in the answer did not apply to $M'$.

**Question**:

I cannot see why the procedure in the answer does not apply to the new set $M'$. Why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function $1/t$ is in $L^2([1,\infty))$ but not $L^2((0,1))$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks a lot! How could I not see it!

Comment: Actually the set $M'$ is not closed. Since $1/t$ is not in $L_2$, the functional $x\mapsto \int_0^1x(t)/t\,dt$ is not continuous. Hence the kernel $M'$ of the functional is not closed.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for the input. I have already solved it.